# Update Widget Periodically Every Second

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, textview, updates

I currently have a widget that uses two `setTextViewText`:

public class DigitalClock extends AppWidgetProvider {

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.digitalclock);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent clockIntent = new Intent(context, DeskClock.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clockIntent, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rl, pendingIntent);
        java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String time = "kk:mm";
        String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


    }

}
}
```

My question is how do I use this to set the two `TextView` every second so the time updates instead of the 30 mins that `appwidgetprovider` allows?
I've heard of using `AlarmManager`, using a `service`, `handler`.... Problem is no one seems to make it clear or give examples of how i would go about doing this.

So if anyone has a clear way to accomplish this I'd greatly appreciate it thanks

Comment: You really should not be updating an app widget every second. Each app widget update is relatively expensive, and doing one every second also means that your process will hang around in memory all of the time. Clocks are best implemented as features of the home screen itself for efficiency.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is this still the case even in newer versions of Android that it is strongly not recommended to update a widget every second? Would every 5 seconds be okay or where does the line go?

Comment: @SimonForsberg: It is even more of an issue now. The only possible way of doing that (or every 5 seconds) would require a foreground service and [a lot of user education](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508455/115145). "where does the line go?" -- with `JobScheduler` or `WorkManager`, you can ask for every-15-minute updates, and you will get whatever they give you, after taking into account Doze mode, app standby, and manufacturer-specific modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have some services running in background. Send broadcast message from that service or activity to the class that extends AppWidgetProvider(in ur case DigitalClock) and then override the onReceive() function of the same class.

Step 1: Send broadcast from a service or somewhere.

Step 2: add onReceive() function in ur DigitalClock class.

```
    public class DigitalClock extends AppWidgetProvider {


        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.digitalclock);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent clockIntent = new Intent(context, DeskClock.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clockIntent, 0);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rl, pendingIntent);
            java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String time = "kk:mm";
            String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


        }

    }
  @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


                super.onReceive(context, intent);
//Do your task here like updating the textviews
}

    }
```

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work anymore.  https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/clte0i/answer_how_to_update_widget_every_minute_on/